# Scrapy extract non-wrapped data

Tags: python, regex, scrapy, expression

I'm trying to extract specific price data with scrapy, but the price is not wrapped in a tag.

How can i compose the price out of this html?

```
<div class="value">
      <span class="currency">€</span>
     39
     <span class="decimal">.98</span>
     <span class="type">New</span>
</div>
```

How can I refine this to 39,98?

**Solution used:**

```
"".join(response.xpath("//section[@class='order order--new order--left']//div[@class='spec  price']//div[@class='value']//text()").re("[0-9.]+"))
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Please take a moment to review our [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all the text nodes inside the element and join:

```
$ scrapy shell file://$PWD/index.html
In [1]: "".join(response.xpath("//div[@class = 'value']//text()").re("[0-9.]+"))
Out[1]: u'39.98'
```

The `.re()` helps to filter digits and dots only.

If there are multiple values in the document:

```
In [2]: ["".join(value.xpath(".//text()").re(r"[0-9.]+")) for value in response.xpath("//div[@class = 'value']")]
Out[2]: [u'39.98']
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great.

But what if there are multiple value classes in the same doc?
My output is ''24.9810019.9810024.9819.98'' now, because there are some other value classes with digits.

Comment: Thank you, but I meant if there are multiple value classes in the document, but I only need one in specific. Some give other values than prices (telephone numbers...)

I narrowed it down to get the correct value class. Hope it is still efficient:

`  "".join(response.xpath("//section[@class='order order--new order--left']//div[@class='spec  price']//div[@class='value']//text()").re("[0-9.]+")) `

Comment: @jef okay, I see what you've posted as a solution - there was no way I could have provided you with one since you have not posted the complete HTML of the page or the related sections or provided a url to the target page. Glad we've solved it here.

Comment: you gave me the solution with the "".join. Did not know that, many thanks!